Restore state of previous composable when navigating back
I'm having some issues with state and navigation in Compose.
I have a screen A with a searchbar. When a result of the search is clicked it navigates to a detail screen and when I navigate back, screen A is back to its initial state (no results, no search bar input, etc). Is there a way to maintain state of screen A when navigating back from detail screen?
I have tried with saveState and restoreState with no luck. I don't know if this is a navigation configuration, or something else...
See video of problem -> https://youtube.com/shorts/j8qRdUu5dNI?feature=share
This is my NavHost:
SharedTransitionLayout {
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding).background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = CardSearchRoute
        ) {

            composable<CardSearchRoute> {
                val viewModel = koinViewModel<CardSearchViewModel>()
                val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                CardSearchScreen(
                    state = state,
                    onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
                    animatedVisibilityScope = this,
                    onCardClicked = {
                        navController.navigate(CardDetailRoute(cardID = it.id))
                    }
                )

            }

            composable<CardDetailRoute> { backStackEntry ->
                val cardID = backStackEntry.toRoute<CardDetailRoute>().cardID
                val viewmodel = koinViewModel<CardDetailViewModel>(parameters = { parametersOf(cardID) })
                val state by viewmodel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                CardDetailScreen(
                    state = state, animatedVisibilityScope = this,
                    onEvent = {}
                )
            }

            composable<ComingSoonRoute> {
                todoScreen("Collection")
            }

            composable<ScanRoute> {
                todoScreen("Scanning")
            }
        }
    }

Here's the code for my screens and Viewmodel:
Search Screen:
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.CardSearchScreen(
    state: UIState,
    onEvent: (UIEvent) -> Unit,
    onCardClicked: (Card) -> Unit,
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope
) {


    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        onEvent(UIEvent.OnSearchBarTextChanged(""))
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        SearchBar(
            windowInsets = WindowInsets(top = 0),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(8.dp)),
            inputField = {
                SearchBarDefaults.InputField(
                    query = state.searchBarText ?: "",
                    onQueryChange = {
                        onEvent(UIEvent.OnSearchBarTextChanged(it))
                    },
                    onSearch = {  },
                    expanded = false,
                    onExpandedChange = {  },
                    placeholder = { Text("Search by name") },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                        cursorColor = Color.White,
                        focusedLabelColor = Color.White, unfocusedPlaceholderColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f), focusedPlaceholderColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                    ),
                    leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null) },
                )
            },
            expanded = false,
            onExpandedChange = {  },
        ) { }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            if (state.isLoading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            } else {
                val cards = state.foundCards.map { it }.toSet()
                LazyColumn (
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    item{
                        CardCarrousel(
                            title = "LEADERS",
                            cards = cards,
                            type = CardType.LEADER,
                            onCardClicked = onCardClicked,
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope
                        )
                    }

                    item{
                        CardCarrousel(
                            title = "BASES",
                            cards = cards,
                            type = CardType.BASE,
                            onCardClicked = onCardClicked,
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope

                        )
                    }

                    item{
                        CardCarrousel(
                            title = "UNITS",
                            cards = cards,
                            type = CardType.UNIT,
                            onCardClicked = onCardClicked,
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope

                        )
                    }

                    item{
                        CardCarrousel(
                            title = "EVENTS",
                            cards = cards,
                            type = CardType.EVENT,
                            onCardClicked = onCardClicked,
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope

                        )
                    }

                    item{
                        CardCarrousel(
                            title = "UPGRADES",
                            cards = cards,
                            type = CardType.UPGRADE,
                            onCardClicked = onCardClicked,
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope

                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

}


Viewmodel:
class CardSearchViewModel(
    private val searchCardUseCase: SearchCardUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(UIState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()


    fun onEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is UIEvent.OnSearchBarTextChanged ->{
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        searchBarText = event.text
                    )
                }
                searchJob?.cancel()
                search()
            }

        }
    }

    var searchJob: Job? = null

    private fun search() {
        searchJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            searchCardUseCase.invoke(_state.value.searchBarText!!).collect { result ->
                result.onLoading { _, _  ->
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = true,
                            foundCards = emptySet()
                        )
                    }
                }.onSuccess { foundCards ->
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            foundCards = foundCards.sortedBy { it.name }.toSet()
                        )
                    }
                }.onFailure {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

data class UIState(
    val searchBarText: String? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val foundCards: Set<Card> = emptySet(),
    val sortType: SortType = SortType.NAME
)
sealed class UIEvent {
    data class OnSearchBarTextChanged(val text: String) : UIEvent()
}


How are you navigating back? Are you using the system back button? If so, anything you've saved with rememberSaveable will be restored automatically.

@ianhanniballake Yes, I’m navigating with system back button (maybe I’ll add a top bar with custom back button later). The problem I have is that I have my state(search results and search query) in viewmodel so I can’t use rememberSaveable(). Any other way to achieve this?

ViewModels on destinations are also kept automatically, so there must be something wrong with how you've written that particular screen and not anything wrong with Navigation. Can you include the code for that screen?

@ianhanniballake I have edited the question with more code. Thanks!

Why are you calling onEvent(UIEvent.OnSearchBarTextChanged("")) every time your screen enters composition?

@ianhanniballake The onEvent call was just to test something I will remove it. Do you think it has something to do with the problem?

What happens when you remove it?

@ianhanniballake okay, just figured it out. I feel so stupid haha. Thanks for your time! :D
